# How to visualize multiple errorbars for one data set with ErrorListPlot?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, display

I have a following problem:

I am performing error analysis for my data set using multiple technics. Obviously, at the end of my analysis I want to compare the errorbars plotting them on the same graph. However, the best I have got for now is

[image]

I really need it to be on one plot and both vertical=( Can Mathematica do that?

Comment: Would you mind posting your entire code instead of a screenshot? Also, I am not quite sure what it is that you want as an end result

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You say you want to display multiple error bars and your picture just shows that. And you want it both vertical ... and what?

Answer (score 6):

one idea..

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
Show[{ErrorListPlot[
   Table[ {{x, Sin[x]}, 
     ErrorBar[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.3, .1]], 
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.1, .1]]]} , {x, 0, 2 Pi, .2}],
    ErrorBarFunction -> 
    Function[{coords, errs}, {Opacity[0.2], 
      Rectangle[coords + {errs[[1, 1]], errs[[2, 1]]}, 
       coords + {errs[[1, 2]], errs[[2, 2]]}]}]],
  ErrorListPlot[
   Table[ {{x, Sin[x]}, 
     ErrorBar[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.3, .1]], 
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.1, .1]]]} , {x, 0, 
     2 Pi, .3}]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Here is an example drawing lines slightly offset:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
offseterror[off_, color_][coords_, errs_] := {color, 
  Line[{off, 0} + coords + # & /@ Transpose[List @@ errs]]}
Show[{
  ErrorListPlot[Table[{{x, Sin[x]},
     ErrorBar[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.3, .1]]]}, {x, 0, 
     2 Pi, .3}], ErrorBarFunction -> offseterror[0, Blue]],
  ErrorListPlot[Table[{{x, Sin[x]},
     ErrorBar[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.2, .1]]]}, {x, 0, 
     2 Pi, .3}], ErrorBarFunction -> offseterror[0.04, Red]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It should be clear how to add the little end bars if you want. I figure it would get too cluttered and you are better off without anyway though.

Comment: Yep, thanks, but that's the same syntax I have used...

Comment: Perfect! Thanks=)