# Plotting multiple datasets with ErrorListPlot

Tags: plotting, functions

What is the equivalent of the code shown below using `ErrorListPlot`? Obviously, I will need to specify error bars, but is `ErrorListPlot` capable of plotting multiple datasets, as is possible with `ListPlot`, `ListLinePlot` and `Plot`?

```
data1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}};
data2 = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 6}, {4, 12}};
data3 = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}};
ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3}]
```

Comment: Have you seen [How to visualize multiple errorbars for one data set with ErrorListPlot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96512/how-to-visualize-multiple-errorbars-for-one-data-set-with-errorlistplot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ErrorListPlot`  can indeed be used to plot multiple datasets using the usual format for plotting:

```
ErrorListPlot[{dataset1,dataset2,dataset3}]
```

First, be sure to load the package

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
```

Let's generate some error bars to go with your example dataset

```
errorlist1 = Table[RandomReal[{0, 2}], {Length[data1]}];
errorlist2 = Table[RandomReal[{0, 2}], {Length[data2]}];
errorlist3 = Table[RandomReal[{0, 2}], {Length[data3]}];
```

When plotting with explicit `{x,y}` coordinates, the syntax is `{{{x1,y1},ErrorBar[value1]},...}` for each point of the plot. For convenience, here's a function that takes the dataset and the list of errors as arguments:

```
datawitherror[data_, errorlist_] := 
Table[{data[[i]], ErrorBar[errorlist[[i]]]},
{i, 1, Length[data]}];
```

And finally the plotting

```
ErrorListPlot[{datawitherror[data1, errorlist1], 
  datawitherror[data2, errorlist2], datawitherror[data3, errorlist3]}]
```

[image]